# C - Input Verification in loop acting weird

Tags: c, loops, if-statement, input, verification

I am writing an input routine that requests a number between 1 and 30 from the user, and which is meant to emit an error message and re-prompt the user for input until valid input is received. I used a loop to read the input and check it against various cases, exiting the loop once appropriate input is received.

The case checking against whether the number is in range works (or did work) perfectly fine, but when I check to make sure that the user did not enter anything non-numeric, the whole thing pretty much blows up in my face, and the loop seems to act weirdly. I was told at first it was an issue with not closing the input buffer so I added that fix, but then despite the condition being met the first time, it would not jump back to the front of the loop to allow the input to be altered -- instead it would immediately jump to a branch and continually print that message on the order or thousands of times per second.

Below is the code. The part that gets continually printed is the `if( isalpha(uNum) ){...`.  For this revision of my code, putting inputs above 30 and below 1 work just fine, but throwing in something like "abc" continually prints the message for going over 30 (i.e. "Value must be at most 30..."). When I take out the statement to clear the buffer ( `while(getchar() != '\n');` ) the aforementioned messages are constantly spammed without end. Can somebody help me out with why that is and/or what I need to do to fix it?

```
int get_seed(void)
{
    int uNum;
    printf("Please enter an integer between 1 and 30:\n");
    while(1) {
        scanf("%d",&uNum);
        while(getchar() != '\n');
        if( isalpha(uNum) ){
            printf("Your entry must start with a digit; try again\n");
        }
        else if( (uNum < 1) || (uNum > 30) ){
            if(uNum<1){
                printf("Value must be at least one; try again\n");
            } else {
                printf("Value must be at most 30; try again\n");
            }
            continue;
        }
        else
            break;
    }
    return uNum;
}
```

At this point I am wondering if it would make more sense to simply change the "else break;" statement (which means the input was good) to have a compound condition of <=30 and >=1 so that a new else statement takes care of what the first if was supposed to do.

Comment: `scanf()` can fail add a check and many of your questions gets answered

Comment: What do you mean by scanf() can fail? I don't understand what kind of check that would require.

Comment: `if(scanf("%d",&uNum) == 1)` { // Scanf succeeded }

Comment: Ok but moving on from there how would I check for non numeric input as that is one of the requirements of the project? Specifically we must have the message "Your entry must start with a digit...." print at the appropriate point

Comment: `isalpha(int n)` is most likely not doing what you want. `scanf()` will have already tried to convert to an integer, and might have failed, leaving the stream pointing at the first character that could not be a part of an integer. You should really check that `scanf()` succeeded. Your `while` loop will happily throw away everything, even valid integer characters, until a newline... Probably a couple other things... Some of those would be caught by turning on compiler warnings and paying attention to them...

Comment: Thats just the thing though, all warnings are on and not a single one gets spit at me. Assuming I were using the check above to see that scanf succeeded, how can I end up with a case where it recognizes non-numeric input and more importantly, would the scanf check be immediately after the scanf and contain all of my existing branches inside of it, then outside have an else branch for it failing?

Comment: check the return to `scanf`, if a matching failure occurs, `uNum` is undefined and you will most likely drop out of your loop at the `break`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scanf` can be a bit tricky when attempting to get input within a loop due to the potential for an infinite loop if you fail to empty stdin between calls to `scanf`. This isn't perfect, but it is a lot closer to what you are looking for. The key is to make use of the return to `scanf` to determine whether a matching failure occurred:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXNUM 30

int main () {

    int uNum = 0;

    printf ("\nEnter a number between 1 and %d:\n", MAXNUM);

    while (printf ("\n  uNum: "))
    {
        int rtn = scanf ("%d", &uNum);
        int c = 0;

        /* check for matching failure, empty input buffer */
        if (rtn == 0) do { c = getchar(); } while ( c != '\n' && c != EOF);

        if (uNum > 0 && uNum < MAXNUM + 1) break;
    }

    printf ("\nValue : %d\n\n", uNum);

    return 0;

}
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/scf130

Enter a number between 1 and 30:

  uNum: a

  uNum: -1

  uNum: 31

  uNum: 18

Value : 18
```

**Note:** this will accept numbers `1 ... 30`, if you want `2 ... 29` simply adjust the tests.

Comment: It will accept the `1` from `1X` -- yes. Just as `strtol, strtoul, etc..` will. If not accepting that is now a new requirement, we can rework the format string or simply skip `scanf` altogether and use a simple pointer.

Comment: Thank you VERY VERY much. I was able to construct my loop to properly work because of your example showing how a check on scanf is necessary. I would also like to thank Gopi and twalberg for the initial suggestion as well as everyone else who took the time to answer me. Thank you all so much.

Comment: Glad to help, good luck with your programming. C is a wonderful language to learn.

Answer (score 1):

The format string `"%d"` instructs `scanf()` to skip any leading whitespace, and attempt to convert characters starting with the first non-whitespace to a signed decimal integer.  This is all well and good as long as the input in fact has that form, but it is not appropriate for reading or validating general input because it **stops** when it encounters characters it cannot match to the pattern.  That may happen either before or after any digits have been read; if before, then nothing is recorded in *uNum.

The return value of `scanf()` tells you how many items from the format were matched, which says, among other things, whether a matching failure happened before any digits were read.  `scanf()` does not tell you *anything*, however, about what's next in the input (that could not be matched).

Moreover, if `scanf()` successfully *does* match a number, then you know already that the part that was matched is, in fact, numeric.  The call to `isalpha()` is therefore not only needless, but **wrong**.  It asks whether the character having code `uNum` is alphabetic, but that's not what you want to know at all.

Additionally, it's unclear *exactly* what form of input you expect, but the `while(getchar() != '\n');` may well *not* be what you want.  If you expect the user to type a response and then press enter to terminate it, then you might be better off reading a line at a time via `fgets()`, and then examining the whole line.  You may find the `strtol()` function useful for both converting the input to a number and determining whether there is are any trailing characters that would render the input invalid (e.g. "1foo").

Answer (score 1):

As advised by commenters, the return value from `scanf()` will tell you the number of fields successfully converted. If the number input is preceded by a non-numeric character, the input will fail. If the number input is followed by a non-numeric character, the conversion will succeed but stop at that point.

So what this solution does is to check what character follows the number input. If it is `newline`, the input was successful.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n;
    char c;
    printf ("Enter a number: ");
    if (2 != scanf("%d%c", &n, &c)) {
        printf ("Invalid number input\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if (c != '\n') {
        printf ("Invalid number input\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if (n<1 || n>30) {
        printf ("Valid range is 1..30\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("You entered %d\n", n);
    return 0;
}
```

Sample program runs:

```
Enter a number: a12
Invalid number input

Enter a number: 12a
Invalid number input

Enter a number: 42
Valid range is 1..30

Enter a number: 12
You entered 12
```

Comment: Depending on the exact input form expected, `!isspace(c)` might be a more appropriate test than `c != '\n'`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger good point, perhaps in some OS the next char might be `'\r'`